# Load data from HDFS to Vertica

Tags: database, hadoop, hdfs, vertica, webhdfs

I am getting following error while loading data from HDFS to vertica

I just stop previously working database & created new database in Vertica. Then I ran

```
vsql -f [AggregateFunctions.sql, AnalyticFunctions.sql, FilterFunctions.sql,
  JavaFunctions.sql, JavaUDLFunctions.sql, ParserFunctions.sql, 
  SourceFunctions.sql, TransformFunctions.sql]
```

When I tried to load data from HDFS using following command

```
COPY exploded001 SOURCE Hdfs(url='http://hadoop-namenode.com:50070/webhdfs/v1/bq-upload/exploded/part-00000', 
 username='xyz') DELIMITER E'\t';
```

I got following ERROR :

```
ERROR 3457:  Function Hdfs() does not exist, or permission is denied for Hdfs()

HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to 
add explicit type casts
```

Comment: It would help to know what version of Vertica you're running on as 7.1 doesn't require the use of connectors.

Comment: First database was working without any connector install, but when I stopped first working DB and created new one, I got this error. I am on Vertica Analytic Database v7.0.1-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run following command to fix this issue

```
vsql -f /opt/vertica/packages/hdfs_connectors/install.sql
```

Comment: For 7.2, path was `/opt/vertica/packages/hdfsconnector/ddl/install.sql`